# Swift physics not working on iOS7

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a simple SpriteKit game that uses physics. Written in Swift, and works great in iOS8 Simulator. 
The node stops at the physicsworld edge.

But when running on iOS7 it falls right trough. Think it has something to do with the category, contact and collision bitmask.

any clue?

Defining the categories here

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None: UInt32 = 0
    static let Edge: UInt32 = 0b1 // 1
    static let Player: UInt32 = 0b10 // 2
    static let Enemy: UInt32 = 0b100 // 4
}
```

Setup World

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.81)
```

Setup Player/Ball/Node

```
playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
playerNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
playerNode.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
playerNode.physicsBody!.mass = 0.50
playerNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
playerNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy | PhysicsCategory.Edge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working!

Updated to Yosemite 10.10.1 and Xcode 6.1.1, created a new project. Strange, but works great now.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm I'm not having that problem.  I almost wrote your code verbatim.  I assumed playerNode is a SKShapeNode and used it's path in `polygonFromPath`  Can you try running this in iOS7 and see if you still have a problem?

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None: UInt32 = 0
    static let Edge: UInt32 = 0b1 // 1
    static let Player: UInt32 = 0b10 // 2
    static let Enemy: UInt32 = 0b100 // 4
}

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let playerNode = SKShapeNode(ellipseInRect: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.81)

        self.addChild(playerNode)


        playerNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: playerNode.path)
        playerNode.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        playerNode.physicsBody!.mass = 0.50
        playerNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        playerNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy | PhysicsCategory.Edge
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working at all. I am not using an SKShapeNode, playerNode is a SKSpriteNote from an image, but i've created a custom path for the PhysicsBody.  -  

[SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithEllipseInRect:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b5aa168.  -  

Looks like shapeNodeWithEllipseInRect only works with iOS8 and above according to the documentation.

Comment: ah yeah.  that makes sense.  they made some new initializers for skshapenode when ios8 came out.